# Export to Access Data to a SharePoint 2013 List via vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, excel-2010, sharepoint-2013

How can I export Access data to SharePoint via VBA?

Comment: I've tried using docmd.transfersharepointlist , but I think I could not use this, because I can't find acExport or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing to a SharePoint list? If so, just add the SharePoint table as a linked table. Then it's just an append query.

Comment: Yes, but I need also update some fields. Is this also possible with an append query?